# Create a new GCP notebook with python 3.10 from console

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I use the command

```bash
gcloud notebooks instances create mynotebookname --vm-image-project=deeplearning-platform-release --vm-image-family="common-cpu" ...
```

to create a GCP notebook. However the image family `common-cpu` currently has `python 3.7`. Which image family or image from this project should I use to have `python 3.10`?

Answer (score 1):

It looks that I can use

```bash
gcloud notebooks instances create mynotebookname \
    --vm-image-project=deeplearning-platform-release \
    --vm-image-name=common-cpu-notebooks-v20230501-debian-11-py310 \
    ---
```

where the list of available images is returned with

```bash
gcloud compute images list --project deeplearning-platform-release | grep notebooks
```